# Working with Lua in C, setting up environment with Code::Blocks and MinGW

Tags: c, linker, lua, mingw, codeblocks

I'm having some difficulty with linking against the Lua 5.1 libraries using Code::Blocks and MinGW so that I can work with Lua in C.  In code blocks, I have search directories pointing to "C:\Program Files(x86)\Lua\5.1\include" and the similar path ending with "\lib" for linking properties, for the includes and libraries tabs, respectively.  I even include "lua51.DLL" and "lua5.1.DLL" in my root folder for the project.  The interesting thing is that is works fine for SDL, which follows the same procedures as what I explained just now.  I've even tried the "magic" fix of linking against "-llua -lliblua" and it doesn't work.  My error is specifically "Main.o: undefined reference to 'lua_dofile'", which I know is a linking error.  Can someone walk me through how TI set thing up right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that it's due to it being [luaL_dofile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_dofile) instead? Note the capital L after lua.

Comment: wow, that was my problem.  Thanks, next time I need to do a better job RTFMing :)